# Convert CSV to ARFF using weka

Tags: weka

I've been trying to get this dataset `http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Communities+and+Crime+Unnormalized` into Weka and no luck at all. I converted it to CSV and then loaded it into Weka and then tried to convert it to ARFF but still giving me the error `"attribute names are not unique"`.

Also, do I have to spread the training dataset from testing dataset or keep them together?

Answer (score 45):

You can also use the ArffViewer (Tools -> ArffViewer or Ctrl+A). Then open your CSV file.

Next go to File -> Save as... and select *Arff data files* (should be selected by default).

Note that your fields must be separated with a comma and not a semicolon.

Comment: I can't find the option to convert numeric to nominal and vice versa in the `ArffViewer`. Does it exist there?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Should be the selected answer

Answer (score 15):

There are some converters implemented in WEKA. Here are the API pages related to this topic: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/converters/package-summary.html

For example here is how to convert from CSV to ARFF:

```
java -cp /path/to/weka.jar weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv > filename.arff
```

Comment: Just a comment for someone dumb like me - Above command is to be run after going to the directory where weka is installed i.e. where you can see `weka/core/converters/CSVLoader` as a directory structure.

Comment: You can also do `java -cp /path/to/weka.jar weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv > filename.arff`

Comment: i get this error 
'Error: Could not find or load main class weka.core.converters.CSVLoader'
how to overcome this?

Comment: Make sure that you included the weka.jar in your classpath (using "-cp <route_of_your_jar>") as in code line in the answer.
Also, make sure that your JAR file contains the CSVLoader class in it!
A JAR file is just a zip file, so double click on it and explore the path "weka/core/converters/". You should find there a CSVLoader.class file.

Answer (score 5):

Upload your .CSV format file to [this](http://ikuz.eu/csv2arff/). From that your .CSV format will be converted to WEKA .arff format. Once it is done fetch .arff file to Weka tool. Now you can proceed with your data analyzing.

Comment: The link would ask you to register to use the converter.

Answer (score 2):

You need header fields in the csv. You need to add attr0,attr1,...,labels in the csv file in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any problem. Okay, do the following. In the web page you specified,

- copy the segment between ".arff header for weka: " and "Relevant Papers".
- paste it on a .txt file
- open the data file at [this location](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00211/)
- copy the instances and append that to your .txt file right after @data section
- save the .txt file as .arff file

You are now good to go.

**do i have to spreate the training dataset from testing dataset or leave them together?**

It depends on your classification method. If you choose 10-fold CV, then leave them together. If you want to use the convention method, separate them. Again, it all depends on your methodology.

Comment: Why on earth someone will give this question a negative vote? Also, as it solves the problem, why on earth my answer got the negative vote? Peculiar!

Comment: OP is asking for CSV to ARFF conversion. But you did not answer that part. Hence someone downvoted I think.

Answer (score 1):

To convert .csv to .arff file format to use in Weka.
**Note :** .csv file should be proper, else it will not convert to .arff file. It should not contain any null value in columns.
Download the weka core jar.
In Eclipse -->Configure Build path, add the weka core jar and write the below line of code  and execute the code:

**CSVToArff.java**

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

import java.io.File;

public class CSVToArff {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    // load CSV
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File("Provide the input file location (.csv) "));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

    // save ARFF
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(data);
    saver.setFile(new File("Provide the output file location (.arff) ");
    saver.writeBatch();
    // .arff file will be created in the output location
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this online CSV to ARFF converter can be useful?

http://slavnik.fe.uni-lj.si/markot/csv2arff/csv2arff.php

Comment: I used the above link, but my values didn't separated . that mean my 8227 lines of file came out with three lines, 1. header,  2.  Attributes,  3.  values.   How to divide them row by row?

Answer (score 0):

In weka using **Simple CLI**, we can convert *.csv* file to a *.arff* file easily.

Simply you have to navigate to Simple CLI -> Give the below command in the text field provided(first provide the .csv file name and then a name for the .arff you wants to convert)

```
java weka.core.converters.CSVLoader D:\L4S1\DataMining-Lab-Assignment-02\filename.csv > D:\L4S1\DataMining-Lab-Assignment-02\filename.arff
```

The below image shows the Simple CLI window

[image]

Answer (score -1):

it works

for example:- C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -cp "e:\data\weka-3-6-10\weka.jar;." weka.core.converters.CSVLoader data1.csv >> data1.arff 1.before conversion check that csv in excel as that any of the cells should not be improper 2.check that attributes are in proper

for plain csv - u must add header row even as x,y,z,... according to need